# How do I calculate the amount from the volume?

Tags: word-problem

I also had this question on my math test the other day and really didn't understand how to do it. I would love to understand how to solve such a problem in the future.

The question is: The gold pavilion in the city of Kyoto is covered with gold leaf. Gold leaf has a thickness of 100 nm (nanometres) and is made from gold bars. A gold bar has a volume of 0.65 dm^3. How many square metres can the gold leaf from a gold bar cover?

I thought I would try to convert the nanometres into decimetres and then calculate the volume. In the end it didn't work so I turn here. How do I do it?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just have to equate the volume of the gold bar to the volume of the gold leaf. If area covered is $A$  $m^2$, then we have:
$$0.65×10^{-3}=100×10^{-9}A$$
Hence you get your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by Am2? Is that the only straightening required to find out how many square meters of gold leaf from a gold bar can cover?

Comment: In order to make gold leaves the gold bars are probably melted, so Poisson's ratio plays no role here. Even if the gold bars are compressed, it's going to be a highly plastic deformation, in which case Poisson's ratio, which assumes linear elasticity, plays no role.

Comment: Sebastian, I meant to write $A$ $m^2$...square metres

Comment: @sams-studio fine then.